# DFP ads in Vue/Nuxt underperforming

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js, google-dfp

I inherited a site with lots of legacy code.  The site has been rewritten from the ground up using VueJS/Nuxt.  Basically everything on the new version of the site is MUCH better, except for the ad revenue.  We are using DFP (doubleclick) for ads on our site.  Before converting to Nuxt, the site was a traditional (non-SPA) site.  The daily/monthly ad revenue has dropped about 25% since the switch.

Unfortunately, I don't have many details, as I am not an expert in ad operations.  Obviously switching to a SPA site presents challenges that weren't there before with ads.  Instead of ads loading fresh going from page-to-page on the old site, when using a SPA, the ad units remain on the page on history/route change.  So I have code in place to automatically refresh ads when a route change occurs.

I guess I'm wondering if anyone out there has any advice for dealing with DFP ads in a SPA.  As I said, ad revenue has decreased about %25, but our traffic remains relatively the same as it was before the site upgrade.  Does anyone know of any potential issues/pitfalls when dealing with DFP ads in a SPA?  Is anyone, more knowledgeable in ad operations interested helping me out optimizing our ad setup?  Or can anyone recommend a specialized ad/developer contractor or some place I can go to find better help?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say about the traffic being the same, do you mean that the ad views count is on the same level as in the previous version? Basically, the drop of revenue means that you either get less ad units and views or the cost of each view has dropped. There is a lot of reasons why the CPM or CTR may drop. Try to compare DFP reports for some equivalent time periods for old version and new version and may be you can get some insights on it.

Comment: Also this may be useful for your case: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/183281

Comment: I would love to try to help, or at least collab on the problem. I am in a similar situation but still in the pre-launch stage and noticing memory leaks / CPU issues coming from DFP. If the traffic is same for you, I would think the issues I am noticing could affect the ad revenue (bottlenecked requests, ect).

Comment: I just tried implementing the destroySlots() call (as suggested above).  Too early to tell if it has made a difference, but I'll post back when I know for sure.